# maven dependency management version for few child modules

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

Lets suppose I have a parent module and it has 100 child modules, I have defined in parent module to use a specific version for all child modules
ex :

```
<dependencyManagement>  
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
         <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
         <version>29.0-jre</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

If i add this in parent pom, all its child used modules uses 29.0-jre
But now i want to use 25.0-jre version for few modules(child), how should i manage this,
I have tried overriding version in child modules but that i need to change all 50 child module pom.xml, is there any better way?

Comment: You wrote ` i want to use 25.0-jre version for few modules(child), ` but you are telling changing 50 child modules? Is `few` equal to `50`?  You have to override the version in the modules you would like to change the version...but I strongly recommend not to do such things otherwise you will bring the idea of depMgmt into useless...and even more worse ... if you upgrade later this means you have to change all the other child modules as well... The question is why do some childs need a different version?

Answer (score 1):

Establish an intermediate level with two parent POMs that contain the dependencyManagement for the two kinds of modules that you have.